# Hibernate ManyToOne and problems with list

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a relation between a parent and child table in which, the parent table has a single primary key and the child table has a composite primary key. However only one of the columns in the child table is referenced to the parent table.

[image]

My hibernate classes are wired up as such:

***Parent Table***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "snippet")
public class SnippetEntity implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3220451853395334879L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "snpt_id", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private String snippetId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "cretn_ts")
    private Date creationTimeStamp;

    @Column(name = "cretn_user_id")
    private String creationUserId;

    public String getSnippetId() {
        return snippetId;
    }
    public void setSnippetId(String snippetId) {
        this.snippetId = snippetId;
    }

    public Date getCreationTimeStamp() {
        return creationTimeStamp;
    }
    public void setCreationTimeStamp(Date creationTimeStamp) {
        this.creationTimeStamp = creationTimeStamp;
    }

    public String getCreationUserId() {
        return creationUserId;
    }
    public void setCreationUserId(String creationUserId) {
        this.creationUserId = creationUserId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SnippetEntity{" +
                "snippetId='" + snippetId + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

***Child Table***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "snippet_detail")
public class SnippetDetailEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7470223455753164243L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "lang_cd", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private String language;

    @Column(name = "snpt_type_cd")
    private String snippetType;

    @Column(name = "snpt_desc")
    private String snippetDescription;

    @Column(name = "snpt_txt")
    private String snippetText;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "cretn_ts")
    private Date creationTimeStamp;

    @Column(name = "cretn_user_id")
    private String creationUserId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updt_ts")
    private Date updatedTimeStamp;

    @Column(name = "updt_user_id")
    private String updatedUserId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="snpt_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private SnippetEntity snippetEntity;

    public SnippetDetailEntity() {}


    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getSnippetType() {
        return snippetType;
    }
    public void setSnippetType(String snippetType) {
        this.snippetType = snippetType;
    }

    public String getSnippetDescription() {
        return snippetDescription;
    }
    public void setSnippetDescription(String snippetDescription) {
        this.snippetDescription = snippetDescription;
    }

    public String getSnippetText() {
        return snippetText;
    }
    public void setSnippetText(String snippetText) {
        this.snippetText = snippetText;
    }

    public Date getCreationTimeStamp() {
        return creationTimeStamp;
    }
    public void setCreationTimeStamp(Date creationTimeStamp) {
        this.creationTimeStamp = creationTimeStamp;
    }

    public String getCreationUserId() {
        return creationUserId;
    }
    public void setCreationUserId(String creationUserId) {
        this.creationUserId = creationUserId;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedTimeStamp() {
        return updatedTimeStamp;
    }
    public void setUpdatedTimeStamp(Date updatedTimeStamp) {
        this.updatedTimeStamp = updatedTimeStamp;
    }

    public String getUpdatedUserId() {
        return updatedUserId;
    }
    public void setUpdatedUserId(String updatedUserId) {
        this.updatedUserId = updatedUserId;
    }

    public SnippetEntity getSnippetEntity() { return snippetEntity; }
    public void setSnippetEntity(SnippetEntity snippetEntity) { this.snippetEntity = snippetEntity; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SnippetDetailEntity{" +
                "language='" + language + '\'' +
                ", snippetType='" + snippetType + '\'' +
                ", snippetDescription='" + snippetDescription + '\'' +
                ", snippetText='" + snippetText + '\'' +
                ", creationTimeStamp=" + creationTimeStamp +
                ", creationUserId='" + creationUserId + '\'' +
                ", updatedTimeStamp=" + updatedTimeStamp +
                ", updatedUserId='" + updatedUserId + '\'' +
                ", snippetEntity=" + snippetEntity +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The call to get all `snippet_detail` is:

```
List<SnippetDetailEntity> snippetEntities = dbService.getAll(SnippetDetailEntity.class);

public <T> List<T> getAll(Class<T> clazz) {
    return getSession().createCriteria(clazz).list();
}
```

There are 378 records in `snippet_detail`. So, my problem is, when I do a list to get all rows from `snippet_detail` I get two unique records (the first two that match the primary keys on this table) from `snippet_detail` and these records are duplicated multiple times. The total number of records are still 378, but these 378 records are made of the two records duplicated multiple times. What I am totally confused about and I admit this maybe due to my understanding of hibernate is why is this happening? I have read through a lot of posts and they all talk about hibernate doing an `outer join`. Is there something wrong I am doing? If so, what do I do to fix this?

UPDATE:

Reading through some more blogs and post I realized that I have a composite key in my `snippet_detail` and the way to handle that with hibernate it to use the `@Embeddable` annotations. I created a `@Embeddable` class that has the `snpt_id` and `lang_cd`. I modified my `snippet_detail` entity class to use the `@Embeddable` class. I also moved the `@ManyToOne` join into the `@Embeddable` class because I figured this is where I need to specify the join condition (i.e. between the `snpt_id` of the `snippet_detail` and the `snpt_id` of the `snippet` table.

**Now, the fetch works fine, but when I insert into the `snippet_detail` I get an hibernate error that says it can't perform the insert because I violate the referential key constraint.** In the classes that I have in my original post, the `@ManyToOne` was within the child class and in that case the insert to the child table would insert a record in the parent snippet table if the record did not already exist in the snippet table.

My parent table class is same as above. The new `@Embeddable` class and my child classes are modified as:

```
@Embeddable
public class SnippetDetailPrimaryEntity implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "snpt_id")
    private SnippetEntity snippetEntity;

    @Column(name = "lang_cd")
    private String language;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "snippet_detail")
public class SnippetDetailEntity implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SnippetDetailPrimaryEntity snippetDetailPrimaryEntity;

    @Column(name = "snpt_type_cd")
    private String snippetType;

    @Column(name = "snpt_desc")
    private String snippetDescription;

    @Column(name = "snpt_txt")
    private String snippetText;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "cretn_ts")
    private Date creationTimeStamp;

    @Column(name = "cretn_user_id")
    private String creationUserId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updt_ts")
    private Date updatedTimeStamp;

    @Column(name = "updt_user_id")
    private String updatedUserId;
}
```

Comment: You talk about two ids in the child table! There's only one i can see ?

Comment: @AtimeneNazim the ‘snpt_id’ and ‘lang_cd’ are the primary keys of my child table.

Comment: I didn’t define snpt_id in my child hibernate class because of the manytoone mapping on the parent.

Comment: So snpt_id isn't a primary key it's a foreign key !

Comment: Snpt_id in snippet table is primary. Snpt_id + lang_cd in snippet_detail is primary key. In snippet_detail the snpt_id only has a foreign key that references snpt_id in snippet table.

Answer (score 0):

So, for a parent child relation where the parent table has a single primary key, child has a composite key and when one of the child's key has a referential constraint back to the parent, this is what worked for me.

**Parent**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "snippet")
public class SnippetEntity implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3220451853395334879L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "snpt_id", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private String snippetId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "cretn_ts")
    private Date creationTimeStamp;

    @Column(name = "cretn_user_id")
    private String creationUserId;
}
```

**Child's composite key as Embeddable:**

```
@Embeddable
public class SnippetDetailPrimaryEntity implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "snpt_id")
    private String snippetId;

    @Column(name = "lang_cd")
    private String language;
}
```

**Child**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "snippet_detail")
public class SnippetDetailEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7470223455753164243L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private SnippetDetailPrimaryEntity snippetDetailPrimaryEntity;

    @Column(name = "snpt_type_cd")
    private String snippetType;

    @Column(name = "snpt_desc")
    private String snippetDescription;

    @Column(name = "snpt_txt")
    private String snippetText;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "cretn_ts")
    private Date creationTimeStamp;

    @Column(name = "cretn_user_id")
    private String creationUserId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updt_ts")
    private Date updatedTimeStamp;

    @Column(name = "updt_user_id")
    private String updatedUserId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="snpt_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private SnippetEntity snippetEntity;
}
```